# Font U/esint/m/n/12=esint10 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found

Tags: fonts, errors, esint

I am getting this error message:

```
(C:\Users\Δημήτρης\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\esint\uesint.fd
)miktex-maketfm.exe: Permission denied: C:\Users\EE49~1\AppData\Local\Temp\mik44600
miktex-maketfm.exe: Data: C:\Users\EE49~1\AppData\Local\Temp\mik44600

! Font U/esint/m/n/12=esint10 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.5 \[
```

when I am trying to use the `esint` package. Here is a Minimal Working Example wich generates this message.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{esint}
\begin{document}

\[
 I = \ointctrclockwise x dx
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I suspect you have a defective installation of `esint`: my system has a Type 1 font for this (`fonts/type1/public/esint-type1/esint10.pfb`). Perhaps have a look in the MiKTeX Package Manager to see what files are supposed to be installed.

Comment: @JosephWright A PFB file is not sufficient, one also needs the TFM file in `.../fonts/tfm/public/esint`

Comment: @JosephWright my system has a Type 1 font as well.

@egreg It looks like the `.../fonts/tfm/public/esint` is missing. Not sure what to do.

Comment: @Dimitris How did you install `esint`? If not with MiKTeX's package manager, try with it.

Comment: @egreg I installed it using basic MiKTex package manage, so if you miss a package it installs it on the fly. I also tried to uninstall the basic MiKTex and install the Net installer which allows you download all packages and install a complete TeX/LaTeX system. I still get the same error though.

Comment: @egreg In the installed files the TFM file is not included for some reason, so I had to download it and put it manualy myself but still same error!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .tfm is not in the distribution nor on CTAN. You have to create it and put it in the relevant place in your system.

Here is how to do that:

1) run the command prompt in the directory that contains esint10.mf; with MiKTeX, it is `…\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\esint`.

2) from the command prompt, run

```
mf \mode=localfont; input esint10.mf
```

You will get these files: `esint10.600gf`, `esint10.log` and `esint10.tfm`. Delete the first two and

3) Create an `esint` directory in

```
C:\Users\Your_Name\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\tfm\public\
```

and move `esint10.tfm` into that directory.

Alternatively, if you want all users to have access to this font, put `esint10.tfm` in a local TeXMF root, say `LocalTeXMF\fonts\tfm\public\`. If this local root doesn't exist (MiKTeX doesn't define it by default, contrary to TeX Live), you can create one with `MiKTeX Settings`, `Roots` tab.

4) Finally refresh the file name data base (FNDB).

Comment: Note that TeX Live *has* the TFM file

Comment: @egreg: Yes, but MiKTeX, nor CTAN don't. So, it might be interesting for MiKTeX users to know what to do. I agree MiKTeX should also have it.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem: Lyx, on Windows, complained about esint.sty.

First, I found and executed `Miktex2.9/miktex/bin/mpm.exe` to download `esint.sty`.

Next, download the esint font; the zip misses `esint.tfm`, so I made a search and found it (364 bytes). Copied it to the `Appdata/Local/...` according to Bernard (thank you).

Finally, ran `Miktex2.9/miktex/bin/mo-admin.exe` and clicked `FNDB`. It works.

It's true it is free, but what a pain. It misses an automated tool to install new fonts. It's like wanting to use a car and being forced to lubricate its gears.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 0):

Install package "symbol" to solve your mistake. Start MiKTeX's
Package Manager (Start -> Programs -> MiKTeX 2.8 -> Maintenance (Admin)
-> Package Manager) and make sure to install the package "symbol".