# Font T2A/cmss/m/n/220=lass5159 at 51.59pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found

Tags: fonts, templates

I am using MikTex 2.9 on Windows.

I want to import one cool template (http://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book) and use it with my own ideas. But there are too many problems with cyrillic fonts.

So, first of all, if someone knows how to do it with cyrillic fonts easily, then let me know, please.

But my qustion is about the error which I get in my own tryings to include this template into my work.

I get this error in log-file:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/cmss/m/n' in size <220> not available
(Font) size <51.59> substituted on input line 85.
! Font T2A/cmss/m/n/220=lass5159 at 51.59pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
```

I searched this question in the Internet but no results because I want this running on Windows.

And I have almost full expansion of Miktex, I have `ec`, `cm` packages installed.

And I've seen this closest to mine question -- [Font U/esint/m/n/12=esint10 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200007/font-u-esint-m-n-12-esint10-at-12-0pt-not-loadable-metric-tfm-file-not-found). But I can't understand analogy what I should do with cm-folders in order to correct this.

Here is MWE(non-working now) with this particular problem:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,9pt]{extbook}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel} 
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter

% numbered part in the table of contents
\newcommand{\@mypartnumtocformat}[2]{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\colorbox{ocre!20}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\ecart}{\color{ocre!70}\Large\sffamily\bfseries\centering#1}}\hskip\esp\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth-\ecart-\esp}{\Large\sffamily\centering#2}}}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% unnumbered part in the table of contents
\newcommand{\@myparttocformat}[1]{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\centering#1}}}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newlength\esp
\setlength\esp{4pt}
\newlength\ecart
\setlength\ecart{1.2cm-\esp}
\newcommand{\thepartimage}{}%
\newcommand{\partimage}[1]{\renewcommand{\thepartimage}{#1}}%
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax%
\refstepcounter{part}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@mypartnumtocformat{\thepart}{#1}}{\partname~\thepart\ ---\ #1}}
\else%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@myparttocformat{#1}}{#1}}%
\fi%
\startcontents%
\markboth{}{}%
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
\fill[ocre!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
\node[anchor=north] at (4cm,-3.25cm){\color{ocre!40}\fontsize{220}{100}\sffamily\bfseries\@Roman\c@part}; 
\node[anchor=south east] at (\paperwidth-1cm,-\paperheight+1cm){\parbox[t][][t]{8.5cm}{
\printcontents{l}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}%
}};
\node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@spart#1{%
\startcontents%
\phantomsection
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
\fill[ocre!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
\node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\protect\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\protect\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\protect\centering #1\quad\mbox{}}}}{#1}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
\if@twoside
\if@openright
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\newpage
\fi
\fi
\if@tempswa
\twocolumn
\fi}

\begin{document}
\part{Первая глава}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you run `updmap --verbose` (as administrator) from the command line?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, it did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cyrillic fonts for the `cmr` font family are only defined at discrete steps and the TFM files are created on demand.

You want a font at 220pt, which is not available.

You can get it by changing the font definition file (a `fix-cyr-cm` package should be really needed).

```
\documentclass[a5paper,9pt]{extbook}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel} 
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\cyrfamily}[5]{%
  \DeclareFontShape{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{
    <-6>    #50500
    <6-7>   #50600
    <7-8>   #50700
    <8-9>   #50800
    <9-10>  #50900
    <10-12> #51000
    <12-17> #51200
    <17-20> #51728
    <20-23> #52074
    <23-28> #52488
    <28-34> #52986
    <35->   #53583
  }{}%
}
\DeclareFontFamily{T2A}{cmss}{}
\cyrfamily{T2A}{cmss}{m}{n}{lass}
\cyrfamily{T2A}{cmss}{m}{sl}{lasi}
\cyrfamily{T2A}{cmss}{m}{it}{lasi}
\cyrfamily{T2A}{cmss}{bx}{n}{lasx}
\cyrfamily{T2A}{cmss}{bx}{it}{laso}
\cyrfamily{T2A}{cmss}{bx}{sl}{laso}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{cmss}{m}{sc}{<->sub*cmr/m/sc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{cmss}{sbc}{n}{<->lassdc10}{}

\makeatletter
% numbered part in the table of contents
\newcommand{\@mypartnumtocformat}[2]{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\colorbox{ocre!20}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\ecart}{\color{ocre!70}\Large\sffamily\bfseries\centering#1}}\hskip\esp\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth-\ecart-\esp}{\Large\sffamily\centering#2}}}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% unnumbered part in the table of contents
\newcommand{\@myparttocformat}[1]{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\centering#1}}}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newlength\esp
\setlength\esp{4pt}
\newlength\ecart
\setlength\ecart{1.2cm-\esp}
\newcommand{\thepartimage}{}%
\newcommand{\partimage}[1]{\renewcommand{\thepartimage}{#1}}%
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax%
\refstepcounter{part}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@mypartnumtocformat{\thepart}{#1}}{\partname~\thepart\ ---\ #1}}
\else%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@myparttocformat{#1}}{#1}}%
\fi%
\startcontents%
\markboth{}{}%
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
\fill[ocre!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
\node[anchor=north] at (4cm,-3.25cm){\color{ocre!40}\fontsize{220}{100}\sffamily\bfseries\@Roman\c@part}; 
\node[anchor=south east] at (\paperwidth-1cm,-\paperheight+1cm){\parbox[t][][t]{8.5cm}{
\printcontents{l}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}%
}};
\node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@spart#1{%
\startcontents%
\phantomsection
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
\fill[ocre!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
\node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\protect\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\protect\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\protect\centering #1\quad\mbox{}}}}{#1}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
\if@twoside
\if@openright
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\newpage
\fi
\fi
\if@tempswa
\twocolumn
\fi}

\begin{document}
\part{Первая глава}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But in my project (non in this particular MWE) new error is comming. '! Font T2A/pag/m/n/220=larm5159 at 51.59pt not loadable' Should I do the same with pag? Or there are another actions?

Comment: Yeah, that worked but I am not TeXpert to state that with pag I should not make another actions.

Comment: @Dida There is no Cyrillic `pag` font family, so the default substitution with `cmss` is made, which brings you back to step 1.

Comment: What do you mean by 'step 1'? And I've noticed that all curved and bold text have dissappered. What should I do?

Comment: I made this in addition to your code to make it work. But there is no bold and curved text now `\DeclareFontFamily{T2A}{pag}{}
\cyrfamily{T2A}{pag}{m}{n}{lass}
\cyrfamily{T2A}{pag}{m}{sl}{lasi}
\cyrfamily{T2A}{pag}{m}{it}{lasi}
\cyrfamily{T2A}{pag}{bx}{n}{lasx}
\cyrfamily{T2A}{pag}{bx}{it}{laso}
\cyrfamily{T2A}{pag}{bx}{sl}{laso}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{pag}{m}{sc}{<->sub*cmr/m/sc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{pag}{sbc}{n}{<->lassdc10}{}`

Comment: @Dida I should have said “back to square 1”, like in the Game of the Goose. You need to use a sans serif font which supports Cyrillic.